# shorthand authentication in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

Can anybody explain me what's wrong with an authentication system like this in asp.net:

```
if(IsUserValidate(UserNameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text))
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
```

`IsUserValidate` is a boolean function that takes username and password and checks to see whether they exist in underlying database or not.

Is anything wrong with this? is there any security or whatever problem if I use this instead of membership and profile features that asp.net offers?

I know built-in membership system is somehow better and has it's own benefits and I also know about custom membership implementation but what I want to know is : why I should work with built-in membership system and it's complexity while I can easily use the above piece of code?

Comment: You didn't provide the code inside IsUserValidate().

Comment: @Mert  It's a method in ORM layer which queries User table to see provided username and password exist in that table or not.